# Modifying innerHTML makes Youtube videos unplayable - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

**Problem**

Run this line of javacript in a chrome extension and all videos on youtube refuses to play (sometimes sound but no image).

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
```

**Background**

I'm trying to make a chrome extension which highlights certain words, in order to do this I analyse the HTML and inserts `<span style = '...' >` -tags in appropriate places.

I modify the webpage by reading and setting `document.body.innerHTML` in javascript. This approach seems to works on most sites, however if I try to set `innerHTML` in any way, videos on YouTube refuses to play.

**Example**

A minimal working example which if added as an exension makes all videos on YouTube unplayable can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12273871/chrome-plugin-test.zip).

Edit: Removed additional info which wasn't part of the problem.

Comment: Those particular error messages are because you have an adblocker, and it's blocking those urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
//Or even
document.body.innerHTML += "<span>text</span>";
```

you are recreating every element that is in body. This breaks any event listeners that were attached to the original elements because those objects no longer exist (new ones do, i.e. clones).

Do not use `innerHTML` to insert dom elements doing so will:

1. cause the events to break like you have already learned
2. will cause the re-rendering of all the other elements which doesn't need to happen, and if you do it often will cause performance issues.

Use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild), [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore), [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) and the other dom functions to add/remove elements.

Comment: Or just use `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>text</span>');`. It has the same intended effect as `document.body.innerHTML += '<pam>text</span>';`, except that the rest of the document is not reparsed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Parsing DOM-elements seems like a much easier solution.